# use odata v3 only in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, odata-v4

For my ASP.Net Core WEB API endpoints, I only want to use ODataV3 instead of ODataV4 how can I make that possible or enforce it, because client is sending data V3 format to the server.

Please don't ask me to update the client because it is also accessing other endpoints from another project of ASP.NET Framework, that are consuming V3 without any issues.

Your assistance would be of great help.